# If I'm using password manager provided by Apple on my iPhone, what would happen if I lose that iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, password, keychain

I just realized something, so I'm curious to know the answer. I bought an iPhone and seem to like the password manager that is built into it. I set up all my email passwords (Gmail and all) in it, as well as all my other logins with random passwords generated by that password manager.

But then it dawned on me, what would happen if I lose that iPhone?

PS. I do not have any other Apple devices.

Comment: What password manager? Is it associated with your Apple ID?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, I think they call it Keychain.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1. For the finder of the iPhone - they would have a locked phone and could not get any information unless they guessed your PIN. Even better would be for you to log in to the iCloud website from another machine (which could be your PC) and use Find My.. to say the phone is lost and then even the PIN would fail.

In Settings->Touch ID there is an option to erase your phone after 10 failed attempts at your PIN.
Find my Phone has to be turned on - it is in Settings->Apple Id

2. For you - you are no worse off than before you have to remember all your passwords.

I use a third party password manager (in my case 1password but there are others) so I can use the passwords on a PC as well as my iPhone.

Comment: OK, I understand. But I don't memorize my passwords. That is why I use the password manager. My question is how to recover access to the iOS keychain if I lose my phone.

Comment: @c00000fd That question is not clear from your question. You need an Apple device to get to your iOS keychain

Comment: Well, that's kinda silly. Do they expect me to buy another iPhone for that. Can I use someone else's iPhone then? Why is there no way to access it online? There should be a giant warning then before people start using their password manager - "WARNING: You about to lock yourself out from all your passwords, unless you buy another apple device!"

Comment: @c00000fd Apple is a hardware company. As for access claim the cost of a new phone on your insurance is the backup. Also this is part of the reason I do use a third party password manager.

Comment: That's a good point. Screw their keychain.